# How to disguise escape character - \" within a string

Tags: java, html, string, escaping

I am facing a little difficulty with a *Syntax highlighter* that I've made and is *90% complete*. What it does is that it reads in the text from the source of a `.java` file, detects *keywords*, *comments*, etc and writes a (colorful) output in an `HTML` file. Sample output from it is:

[image: Working]

(I couldn't upload a whole html page, so this is a screenshot.) As (I hope) you can see, my program seems to work correctly with `keywords`, `literals` and `comments` (see below) and hence can normally *document* almost all programs. But it seems to break apart when I store the escape sequence for `"` i.e. `\"` inside a `String`. An *error  case* is shown below:

[image: Not Working]

The string literal highlighting doesn't stop at the end of the literal, but continues until it finds another cue, like a keyword or another literal.

**So, the question is how do I disguise/hide/remove this `\"` from within a `String`?**

The `stringFilter` method of my program is:

```
public String stringFilter(String line) {
    if (line == null || line.equals("")) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    if (line.indexOf("\"") <= -1) {
        return keywordFilter(line);
    }
    int start = 0;
    int startStringIndex = -1;
    int endStringIndex = -1;
    int tempIndex;
    //Keep moving through String characters until we want to stop...
    while ((tempIndex = line.indexOf("\"")) > -1 && !isInsideString(line, tempIndex)) {
        //We found the beginning of a string
        if (startStringIndex == -1) {
            startStringIndex = 0;
            buf.append( stringFilter(line.substring(start,tempIndex)) );
            buf.append("</font>");
            buf.append(literal).append("\"");
            line = line.substring(tempIndex+1);
        }
        //Must be at the end
        else {
            startStringIndex = -1;
            endStringIndex = tempIndex;
            buf.append(line.substring(0,endStringIndex+1));
            buf.append("</font>");
            buf.append(normal);
            line = line.substring(endStringIndex+1);
        }
    }

    buf.append( keywordFilter(line) );

    return buf.toString();
}
```

---

**EDIT**

in response to the first few comments and answers, here's what I tried:

A snippet from `htmlFilter(String)`, but it doesn't work :(

```
    //replace '&' i.e. ampersands with HTML escape sequence for ampersand.
    line = line.replaceAll("&", "&amp;");

    //line = line.replaceAll(" ", "&nbsp;");
    line = line.replaceAll("" + (char)35, "&#35;");

    // replace less-than signs which might be confused
    // by HTML as tag angle-brackets;
    line = line.replaceAll("<", "&lt;");
    // replace greater-than signs which might be confused
    // by HTML as tag angle-brackets;
    line = line.replaceAll(">", "&gt;");

    line = multiLineCommentFilter(line);


    //replace the '\\' i.e. escape for backslash with HTML escape sequences.
    //fixes a problem when backslashes preceed quotes.
    //line = line.replaceAll("\\\"", "&#92;&quot;");
    //line = line.replaceAll("" + (char)92 + (char)92, "&#92;&#92;");
    return line;
```

Comment: Find all HTML escape character and replace it with HTML entities such as Use &quot; in place of double quote("), &amp; in place of &, &gt; in place of < etc. Is it working?

Comment: Well, i did that to no avail.

Comment: Just replace \" with \&quot;

Comment: Check for char found at tempIndex-1 it it is \ then don't consider as beginning or ending of string.

Comment: I tried that bit, but I found that it results in a lot of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is that when a backslash is met, ignore the next character.

```
String str = "blah\"blah\\blah\n";

int index = 0;
while (true) {
    // find the beginning
    while (index < str.length() && str.charAt(index) != '\"')
        index++;
    int beginIndex = index;
    if (index == str.length()) // no string found
        break;
    index++;
    // find the ending
    while (index < str.length()) {
        if (str.charAt(index) == '\\') {
            // escape, ignore the next character
            index += 2;
        } else if (str.charAt(index) == '\"') {
            // end of string found
            System.out.println(beginIndex + " " + index);
            break;
        } else {
            // plain content
            index++;
        }
    }
    if (index >= str.length())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote");
    index++;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the really simple solution... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check for char found at tempIndex-1 it it is \ then don't consider as beginning or ending of string.

```
String originalLine=line;
if ((tempIndex = originalLine.indexOf("\"", tempIndex + 1)) > -1) {
            if (tempIndex==0 || originalLine.charAt(tempIndex - 1) != '\\') { 
...
```

Comment: Run it in Debug mode and try to find the reason. I have updated my code. Check for tempIndex first before checking previous character.

Comment: It gives a `StringIndexOutOfBounds` exception. The `index` comes to `-2`.

Comment: No... it completely ignores all the normal strings and still exceeds the end of the string.

Comment: Let me code it. I will come back with full proof code.

Comment: Check it now.Uuse formIndex in indexOf() method from original line. It can cause problem because you are updating line every time after doing substring and tempIndex is calculated from original line. Just modify your code in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow:

- First replace all \" with some temp string such as

  ```
  String tempStr="forward_slash_followed_by_double_quote";
  line = line.replaceAll("\\\\\"", tempStr);
  //line = line.replaceAll("\\\"", tempStr);
  ```
- do what ever you are doing
- Finally replace that temp string with \"

  ```
  line = line.replaceAll(tempStr, "\\\\\"");
  //line = line.replaceAll(tempStr, "\\\"");
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with finding a quote and then trying to work out whether it's escaped is that it's not enough to simply look at the previous character to see if it's a backslash - consider

```
String basedir = "C:\\Users\\";
```

where the `\"` isn't an escaped quote, but is actually an escaped backslash followed by an unescaped quote.  In general a quote preceded by an *odd* number of backslashes is escaped, one preceded by an *even* number of backslashes isn't.

A more sensible approach would be to parse through the string one character at a time from left to right rather than trying to jump ahead to quote characters.  If you don't want to have to learn a proper parser generator like JavaCC or antlr then you can tackle this case with regular expressions using the `\G` anchor (to force each subsequent match to start at the end of the previous one with no gaps) - if we assume that `str` is a substring of your input starting with the character following the opening quote of a string literal then

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\G(?:\\\\u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}|\\\\.|[^\"\\\\])");
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find()) buf.append(m.group());
```

will leave `buf` containing the content of the string literal up to but not including the closing quote, and will handle escapes like `\"`, `\\` and unicode escapes `\uNNNN`.

Comment: Thanx for the brilliant solution. :-) Maybe it's time I'd better get started learning about `java.util.regex` package...

Answer (score 0):

Use double slash "\\"" instead of "\""... Maybe it works...

Comment: _double slash "\""_? What does it mean?